# Updating a matrix on Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, matrix

When running the following Python code:

```
mat1=[[0]*3]*3
mat2=[[0 for i in range(3)] for j in range(3)]

if(mat1==mat2):
    print("Same content")

mat1[1][1]=7
mat2[1][1]=7

print(mat1)
print(mat2)
```

I get this result:

```
Same content
[[0, 7, 0], [0, 7, 0], [0, 7, 0]]
[[0, 0, 0], [0, 7, 0], [0, 0, 0]]
```

Why is there a difference in the result, and what's wrong with my first way of initializing a matrix?

Comment: Short answer, because `mat1=[[0]*3]*3` creates a *list of lists* where the sublists *are all the same list*. That is how the `*` works in Python. So, `[x]*3` is equivalent to `[x, x, x]`. Note, this is consistent with the `+` concatenation operator on lists, i.e. `a_list + a_list + a_list` is equivalent to `a_list * 3`